# Coordinate confusion with st_crop

Tags: r, r-sf

I wish to crop an sf object. When I plot the object in ggplot I estimate the area I wish to crop. However, when I execute the crop with `st_crop` the tibble has zero rows. Why is this?

Download alberta_border.RDS from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nq6bdaqgmu7txk/alberta_border.RDS?dl=0)

```
library("sf")
library("ggplot2")

alberta <- readRDS("alberta_border.RDS")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = alberta) +
  coord_sf()


alberta_crop <- st_crop(alberta, c(xmin = -118, xmax = -112, ymin = 50, ymax = 56))
alberta_crop
```

Comment: I think your crop limits are incorrect. If you try ```alberta[[7]]```, you get, among other things ```bbox:           xmin: 302466.5 ymin: 5431602 xmax: 1011451 ymax: 6672079```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong `crs`. You can tell the crs of the alberta shapefile:

```r
st_crs(alberta)
#Coordinate Reference System:
#EPSG: 26911 
#proj4string: "+proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Your input file is using `EPSG 26911` or [UTM zone 11N](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-utm-zone-11n/), while it looks like the coordinates you've typed (`c(xmin = -118, xmax = -112, ymin = 50, ymax = 56)`) are lat/lng, or `EPSG 4326`.

We should therefore convert the original dataset to lat/lng before cropping:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

alberta <- alberta %>%
  st_transform(4326)

alberta_crop <- st_crop(alberta, c(xmin = -118, xmax = -112, ymin = 50, ymax = 56))


ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = alberta, aes(fill = 'alberta')) + 
  geom_sf(data = alberta_crop, aes(fill = 'cropped')) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]